# Is there a good mib browser for linux?

Tags: linux, snmp

I am looking for a good open source mib browser for linux. ireasoning has a limit on the number of mib files it can load in the free version.

I dont need it to do mib queries I just need to see the mib tree.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for _Server Fault_ or _Super User_

Comment: @Eero: Even in serverfault, they close such questions saying that it is a product recommendation question. I don't see why people shouldn't ask such questions. A google search brought me to this page, and I feel that the answers to such questions will be really helpful for people.

Comment: @Nav I believe (I can't speak for SE) the rationale is that such questions are opinionated and have no real answer as needs and evaluation criteria can be entirely different. Additionally, any answer provided can change very rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

Try [iReasoning](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml). It is very good one and it has got different useful features.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful tool indeed.

Answer (score 0):

#SNMP Suite has a basic MIB browser available (basic, not good yet),

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com

And you can use it on Mono/Linux.

1. Install Mono.
2. Download the binary zip package.
3. Unzip the contents.
4. At terminal execute `mono compiler.exe` to launch the compiler. Compile the MIB documents. .module files are saved to the default location.
5. At terminal execute `mono browser.exe` to launch the browser. The browser loads the MIB documents from default location.

Be sure to use the compiler to compile the MIB documents to .module files. The browser can only understand .module files.